# If statements for registering in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In my app, this PHP code should check for existing usernames and if one exists, don't create a new row in the database. No matter what, the app still creates new rows in the MySQL database.

Here is the code for checking:

```
<?php 

//$password = "password";
//$username = "username";
require "conn.php";
$password = $_POST["password"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
//$url_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username ='$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0){
   break;
}else{
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UserData (username,password) VALUES (:username,:password)");
$params = array(
    ':username' => $username,
    ':password' => $password
);
$stmt->execute($params);
}

?>
```

Comment: you **MUST NOT** use `mysql_xxx` functions which are deprecated since php5.5 (more than 3 years ago) and removed since PHP7 because of security issues (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/3992945). Please use `mysqli_xxx` or `PDO` instead http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php.

Comment: This is the wrong way to go about this to begin with. You want to make the username field UNIQUE in your database scheme, and then check if an error violating this constraint occurs when you try and insert a new record.

Comment: Check both the contents of `$sql` and the return value of `mysql_num_rows($result)`.  Also the break statement doesn't really belong here; it's for use in loops.  But it doesn't do anything at all, which is probably what you want.  Also the advice from CROZET about using modern/supported mysql libraries is definitely something to heed

Comment: You are mixing mysql and mysqli functions and also you mix object and procedural code

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username ='$username'");
if ($results) { 
    if($results->num_rows === 0)
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UserData (username,password) VALUES (:username,:password)");
        $params = array(
            ':username' => $username,
            ':password' => $password
        );
        $stmt->execute($params);
    }
}
?>
```

1. You should use `mysqli` and not `mysql` as it is deprecated
2. Secondly, you should check `if($results->num_rows === 0)` and do your `INSERT`

Comment: But it crashes when it runs and doesn't add new rows.

Comment: What do you mean by _crashes_? And did you check `echo $results->num_rows`? Is that equal to 0?

Comment: We implemented your code into an Android app, and it crashes when there are no examples of previous usernames that match the current one.

Comment: Okay, so you can change it to `mysqli_query()` and check. Also, check the logs for errors.

Comment: Please be more specific. I am a beginner.

Comment: if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username ='$username' ", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)){}

Comment: Yes, that's correct and I hope you have done proper mysql connection using `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");`

Comment: What is the importance of "$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");". We used a separate php file name conn.php

Comment: That code connects your PHP to MySQL, you can have it separate file and include it in all remaining files.

Comment: conn.php code:                                                                <?php 
$db_name = "xxx";
$mysql_username = "xxx";
$mysql_password = "xxx";
$server_name = "localhost";
//$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password,$db_name);
$conn = new pdo("mysql:host=$server_name;dbname=$db_name",$mysql_username,$mysql_password,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE =>
PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
if ($conn) {
   echo "Connected successfully";
  
} 
if (!$conn) {
   echo "no";
}

?>